# Import error for google api client in django project

Tags: python, django, importerror, google-api-client

I am running django version 1.10.3 and I installed google api client with pip like so:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

When I try to use it with PyCharm/Terminal outside of a django project it works just fine. However, when I try to import it in my django project it throws this error:

```
ImportError: No module named googleapiclient
```

For this import statement:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
```

I don't use any virtual env and nothing. Does anybody know why this error occurs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have not set your python path correctly

Comment: could you explain in more detail what I have to change? Everything else in django is working just fine

Comment: to begin with , please provide full details including whether you are using a virtualenv, what your pythonpath looks like at the moment etc

Comment: I do not use any virtualenv, my python path is the following:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin